# retrieve value from mysql in php with time format as hh:mm

Tags: php, mysql

just telling i have just started coding in php,
I have made this program which fetches data from the database and prints it in the form of a table. In my database the data is stored in a hh:mm:ss format and i wanted the data to be retrieved in a hh:mm way. how should i do this? bell_time is the row which has the time and the name of my database is bell_db. i have used phpmyadmin and mysql. i saw the other posts about this i could not understand them.

```
    // connect to the database
    include('database.php');

    // get results from database
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM bell_db") 
        or die(mysqli_error($conn));  

    // display data in table

    echo "<table border='1' cellpadding='10' class='table table-hover'>";
    echo "<thead><tr> <th>Bell No.</th> <th>No. of Rings</th> <th>Time</th> <th>Period</th> <th></th> <th></th></tr></thead>";
    echo "<tbody>";

    // loop through results of database query, displaying them in the table
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array( $result )) {

        // echo out the contents of each row into a table
        echo "<tr>";
        echo '<td>' . $row['bell_no'] . '</td>';
        echo '<td>' . $row['bell_amount'] . '</td>';
        echo '<td>' . $row['bell_time'] . '</td>';
        echo '<td>' . $row['bell_period'] . '</td>';
        echo '<td><a href="edit.php?bell_no=' . $row['bell_no'] . '">Edit</a></td>';
        echo '<td><a href="delete.php?bell_no=' . $row['bell_no'] . '">Delete</a></td>';
        echo "</tr>"; 
    } 

    // close table>
    echo "</tbody>";
    echo "</table>";
?>
```

Comment: Google "PHP format date time", first result: http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php

Comment: Probably `date("h:i", $row['bell_time'])` or "H:i" if you want 24 hour

Comment: Can you tell us more about your table structure? What type has your column in database table?

Comment: @zajonc my table has 4 rows, bell_no(int), bell_amount(int), bell_time(time) and bell_period(varchar)

Comment: Look at the Mahesh answer it's looking good for your problem.

Comment: @Fred-ii- it doesn't matter if s/he is ignoring you, the community is self-correcting. Over time people will tend to downvote or ignore questions from such users and that's about it. Nothing more is necessary or is to be done here imho.

Comment: @Creos You have a point there.

Comment: @Fred-ii- i do understand your frustration though. Based on your comments, I checked Dhruva's history and indeed they never accept answers despite positive comments from him/her that say they have been helped...

Comment: @Creos I won't be posting my message to people about accepting answers anymore; it seems to be a waste of time. If the gracious people who have provided them with answers feel the need to mark it as solved, then so be it. Stack's (continuing) success was based/conceived on the "rep system". As to why some don't want or feel the need to abide by it, then I would call it ignorance on their part and is a bit baffling if you ask me. Ok, "moving on" ;-) *Cheers*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it with PHP, example :

```
<?php
$tim = "hh:mm:ss";
echo substr( $tim,0,5 );   // RETURNS "hh:mm".
?>
```

In your code :

```
echo '<td>' . substr( $row['bell_time'],0,5 ) . '</td>';
```

The syntax for "substr" is :

```
substr( string , first position , how many chars ).
```

Comment: wow thank you very much it worked. thats a new way of doing it. cool and thnx :D

Comment: @Dhruva, well, you may accept the answer ^_º (click on the checkmark).

Comment: *"wow thank you very much it worked. thats a new way of doing it. cool and thnx :D – Dhruva"* - Which translates to *"Thanks sucker, bye!!"*. Lord knows I tried to set this guy on the right path, but has ignored everything that was said. Upvoted for your troubles.

Comment: @Fred-ii-, I guess you are right.

Comment: @JoseManuelAbarcaRodríguez Unfortunately, yes.

Answer (score 1):

change your query

```
    SELECT * FROM bell_db
```

and get  required fields

```
  select bell_no,...,TIME_FORMAT(bell_time,'%H:%i').... FROM bell_db
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace:

```
echo '<td>' . $row['bell_time'] . '</td>'
```

Use:

```
echo '<td>' . date('H:i', strtotime($row['bell_period'])) . '</td>';
```